# Correct way to set up a Maven POM to compile mixed Java/Groovy code in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a very simple test project in Intellij IDEA in which I try to mix Java 9 and Groovy code. Additionally, this project has [Maven Support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html), i.e. it is organized according to a Maven archetype and has a POM.

Now I have two classes in the default package calling each other (though not cyclically as compilation for that fails) and all is working well, i.e. *Build > Build Project* and *Run > Run 'Main'* are working.

However, this compilation seems to be independent of Maven configuration. There is no Groovy support in the POM for one. If I just compile from the command line with `mvn compile` compilation fails as the linker cannot find any object that would result from Groovy compilation.

The POM just contains configuration for the `maven-compiler-plugin` and I added that by hand with `source` and `target` nodes under `configuration` set to `1.9` to have IDEA compile from/to Java 9 instead of from/to Java 5. So there is some interaction between what is in the POM and what IDEA does when I select `Rebuild Project`.

What is correct way to configure IDEA and/or configure the POM so that compilation succeeds both in IDEA and on the command line. And if anyone knows, what are the interactions between what's in the POM and IDEA?

Do I have to configure the [Groovy Eclipse Maven plugin](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin) in the POM? (I will try to do that)

Comment: IDEA uses pom.xml as an initial source of project configuration. So, IDEA build and Maven build should work the same way. IDEA might detect groovy files and suggest to add Groovy SDK to the classpath, but this change (like any other manual change in project configuration) will be removed on "Reimport" from Maven tool window. So, you could try to run "Reimport" and check if groovy is still mentioned in project dependencies. If you need to build grovy using maven dependency on groovy library should be added to your pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have working for Java 8 and Eclipse, for a project with both Java and Groovy code. I know I found the basis for this via Google at one point but did not save the URL, alas. Not sure if it will work with Java 9 and IntelliJ but worth a shot?

```
<properties>
  <groovy.eclipse.compiler.plugin.version>2.9.1-01</groovy.eclipse.compiler.plugin.version>
</properties>
....
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

  <!-- 2.8.0-01 and later require maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 or higher -->
  <configuration>
    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
    <!-- set verbose to be true if you want lots of uninteresting messages -->
    <!-- <verbose>true</verbose> -->
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.eclipse.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for 2.8.0-01 and later you must have an explicit dependency on groovy-eclipse-batch -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.7-01</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>${groovy.eclipse.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>  <!-- required to get plugin to compile tests when no src/main/java dir exists -->
</plugin>
```